# How should I handle BusinessLogic-related data definitions (like status types) in Doctrine 2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Let's assume I have a `Booking` entity and it has a `state` field which may be set to one of a few values - let's make it: `NEW`, `ACCEPTED`, and `REJECTED`

I am looking for the "right" way to implement this. So far I used an approach like this:

```
class Booking
{
    const STATUS_NEW = 0;
    const STATUS_ACCEPTED = 1;
    const STATUS_REJECTED = 2;

    protected $status = self::STATUS_ACTIVE;
}
```

And it works ok, but I am really curious of the "proper" way of doing, also I have a few problems with this approach:

1. It looks awfully lot like a business logic hidden in the entity class - if entity is supposed to be a `POJO`, then why would it care what the status may be? So I could put it in a manager class like:

   ```
   class BookingManager
   {
       const STATUS_NEW = 0;
       const STATUS_ACCEPTED = 1;
       const STATUS_REJECTED = 2;

       public function setBookingStatus(Booking $b, $status) { }

   }
   ```

   but it still does not help with the second issue:
2. It is hard to re-use that data in the view, let's take a twig for example - I would have to create a Twig Extension in order to convert a number into an actual name:

   ```
   Status type: {{ booking.status }}
   Status name: {{ booking.status|statusName }}{# I don't like this approach #} 
   Status name: {{ booking.getStatusName() }}  {# This seems even worse #}
   ```

   So I could add `getStatusName` method to the `BookingManager` but I believe it does not belong there. I could add the same method to the `Booking` class and it would work just fine, but then again - business logic AND now also presentation logic is hidden in the entity.
3. If some of my code depends on `MyVendor\MyBundle\Entity\Booking::STATUS_NEW` then could it become a problem when unit-testing the code? With static method calls the problem is obvious - I cannot mock the dependency. Is there any use case where depending on static constants may be a problem?

All I could think of would be moving all this logic to the service layer and create a service like `BookingStatusManager` (let's ignore the fact that it could be mistakenly took for an EntityManager subclass) - it could look like this:

```
class BookingStatusManager
{
    const STATUS_NEW = 0;
    const STATUS_ACCEPTED = 1;
    const STATUS_REJECTED = 2;

    public function getStatusName($code) { ... }

}
```

but now I need an extra class for each `enum`-like property for each entity and it's a pain, also it still does not seem right - I need to reference static values from this class whenever I want to deal with `Booking`'s status.

Note that this is a general question, not one specific to presented `Booking` example - it could be for example `BorderLength` entity with `lengthUnit` field with possible values of  `MILES` or `KILOMETERS`; also, status transitions are not restricted to those caused by users, it must be possible to perform these from the code.

What in your experience is "the right way" to solve this?

Comment: I won't claim it's the right or proper way but I make my status fields strings and just put in a human readable value such as New, Accepted, Rejected.  Makes life much easier.

Comment: @Cerad That still leaves problems #1 and #3, but it solves #2 and I quite like it for that, thanks :)

Comment: I agree with @cerad and I do the same thing. Makes for more readable database entires too if that's any sort of benefit. I don't see #3 as being a problem at all and it's never been an issue for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Answers to your numbered questions

**1**: Why *wouldn't* you have business logic in your business model/objects?

Coupling data and behaviour is, after all, one of the very purposes of object orientation? I believe you may have misunderstood the "[POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object)" concept (and I'm not talking about the J standing for Java ;)), whose purpose was to not let *frameworks* invade your model, thus limiting the model to a framework-specific context and making unit testing or re-use in any other context difficult.

What you're talking about sounds more like [DTOs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object), which generally is *not* what your model should consist of.

**2**: Yes, Twig is not terribly good at manipulating numbers-that-symbolizes-meaning. You'll probably get all kinds of suggestions based on things like optimization of storage (number of bytes) or database traffic/query time, but for most projects I prefer prioritizing the human experience - i.e. don't optimize for computers unless you need it.

Thus, my personal preference (in most circumstances) is instantly dev-readable "enum" fields, but in a key-like notation instead of regular words. For example, `"status.accepted"` as opposed to `1` or `"Accepted"`. Key-like notations lend themselves well to i18n, using twig's [`|trans` filter, `{% trans %}` tag](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#translations-in-templates) or something similar.

**3**: Static "enum" references *within* your model is rarely a problem while unit testing the model itself.

At some point your model needs to define its semantics anyway, through the use of the building blocks you have available. While being able to abstract away *implementations* (particularly of services) is useful, being able to abstract away *meaning* is rarely (never?) fruitful. Which reminds me of [this](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/It_Depends_on_Your_Definition_of_True.aspx) story. Don't go there. :-D

If you're still concerned about it, put the constants in an interface that the model class implements; then your tests can reference only the interface.

#### Suggested solution

Model, alternative 1:

```
class Booking {
    const STATUS_NEW      = 'status.new';
    const STATUS_ACCEPTED = 'status.accepted';
    const STATUS_REJECTED = 'status.rejected';

    protected $status = self::STATUS_NEW;
}
```

Model, alternative 2:

```
interface BookingInterface {
    const STATUS_NEW      = 'status.new';
    const STATUS_ACCEPTED = 'status.accepted';
    const STATUS_REJECTED = 'status.rejected';

    // ...and possibly methods that you want to expose in the interface.
}
class Booking implements BookingInterface {
    protected $status = self::STATUS_NEW;
}
```

Twig:

```
Status name: {{ ("booking."~booking.status)|trans({}, 'mybundle') }}
```

(Of course, the `booking.` prefix is optional and depends on the way you want to structure your i18n keys and files.)

Resources/translations/mybundle.en.yml:

```
booking.status.new:      New
booking.status.accepted: Accepted
booking.status.rejected: Rejected
```

#### Constants-as-entities

On [Tomdarkness](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1248820/tomdarkness)' suggestion of turning these constants into their own model class, I want to stress that this should be a business/domain decision, and *not* a question of technical preference.

If you clearly foresee the use cases for *dynamically* adding statuses (supplied by the system's users), then by all means a new model/entity class is the right choice. But if the statuses are used for internal state in the application, which is coupled to the actual code you're writing (and thus won't change until the code changes too), then you're better off using constants.

Constants-as-entities makes working with them much harder ("hm, how do I get the primary key of 'accepted', again?"), isn't as easily internationalizable ("hm, do I store the possible locales as hard-coded properties on the BookingStatus entity or do I make another BookingStatusI18nStrings(id, locale, value) entity?"), plus the refactoring issue you brought up yourself. In short: don't overengineer - and good luck. ;-)

Comment: The only answer that actually addresses all my concerns, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I'd propose you get rid of of the constants and just create a Many-To-One association on your  `Booking` entity with a new `BookingStatus` entity. Why? Well for a number of reasons:

- Does not require editing of code if you wish to add a new booking status. Not only is this easier for developers but also allows the possibility of statuses to be dynamically created.
- You can easily store additional information about the status in the new `BookingStatus` entity, e.g name. This information can also be updated without altering code.
- Allows external tools to understand different statuses. For example you might want to use a external reporting tool directly on the database. It won't know what some integers mean but it will be able to understand a Many-To-One association.

Comment: That sounds good actually, but how do I set a booking status to e.g. `ACCEPTED`? I can retrieve the right ID from the database relying on some unique field, e.g. some kind of `status_type int unique`, but I need to know which number maps to which `status_type`, so I still need those constants to identify the appropriate entity

Comment: It really comes down to how you design your application and how flexible you want to be. Ideally you'd never hard code the setting of a specific status id anywhere therefore you'd never need any constants. So rather than how do I set a booking status to `ACCEPTED` it would be how would the user set the status to a valid value. If you have a workflow where a booking goes from new to accepted, what happens if I want to change this workflow? If some status id was hardcoded it would be more difficult. I hope you can see where I am going with this.

Comment: I like this approach if you need to use the status name as a value in your templates. Another side-benefit to @Tomdarkness approach here is if you use a bi-directional ManyToOne association. If you want to retrieve a BookingStatus `ACCEPTED` and all of the accepted bookings are available as a property of the status entity.

Comment: @Tomdarkness I see, I think it may be a bit of an overkill to create such a framework (m2m, workflow definition in the DB, etc) for each status-alike field, however it certainly solves all the issues I wrote about so I up voted your answer :) I will wait with accepting to see if anyone has something else to add, thanks!

Comment: @Tomdarkness Actually when I think about it - it will work only when every status transition is up to user. If setting a booking to `ACCEPTED`/`REJECTED` is done by e.g. cronjob requesting vendor API to see if there are spare rooms, then this cronjob needs to know which status stands for `ACCEPTED` and which for `REJECTED` so we are back to constants again :(

Comment: @AdamZieliński Your business logic should fit nicely in a custom repository method, but you can search and set status using the base repository methods: `$acceptedStatus = $repository->findOneByName('Accepted');`, `$acceptedStatus->getBookings();` or `$booking->setStatus($acceptedStatus);`

Comment: I can still search by status without the relation;In some case calls like `$repository->findOneByName('Accepted')` could be acceptable, but: 1. I have to remember the status name throughout the application, 2. I am screwed if the name has to change or some smartass changes it in phpmyadmin ("like oh, 'Success' would fit so much better") 3. I cannot use automated refactoring 4. I cannot easily check available statuses (like with constants); so I still need some hardcoded unique token map to identify each entity; then, if I need to add a status I need to do it both in the map and in the database

Answer (score 3):

I use very simple approach. Example:

```
class Offer extends Entity implements CrudEntityInterface
{
    const STATUS_CANCELED = -1;
    const STATUS_IN_PROGRESS = 0;
    const STATUS_FINISHED = 1;
    const STATUS_CONFIRMED = 2;

    protected static $statuses_names = [
        self::STATUS_CANCELED => 'canceled',
        self::STATUS_IN_PROGRESS => 'in_progress',
        self::STATUS_FINISHED => 'finished',
        self::STATUS_CONFIRMED => 'confirmed'
    ];

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="integer")
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    protected $status = self::STATUS_IN_PROGRESS;

    public static function getStatuses()
    {
        return self::$statuses_names;
    }

    /**
     * Set status
     *
     * @param integer $status
     * @return Offer
     */
    protected function setStatus($status)
    {
        if(!array_key_exists($status, self::$statuses_names)){
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Status doesn\'t exist');
        }

        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get status
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    public function getStatusName()
    {
        return self::$statuses_names[$this->status];
    }
}
```

All display names are always translated, in order to keep separation from model

```
{{ ('offer.statuses.'~offer.statusName)|trans }}
```

Comment: do the same +1, especially translation

Answer (score 1):

While it's not the most elegant, you can get a little pragmatic, and just use string keys in a fairly efficient, safe, way:

```
<?php

class Booking
{

    protected $statusMap = array(
        0 => 'new',
        1 => 'accepted',
        2 => 'rejected'
    );

    /**
     * A premature optimization, trading memory to reduce calls to
     * array_flip/array_search in a more naive implementation
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $statusMapReverse;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->statusMapReverse = array_flip($this->statusMap);
        $this->setStatus('new');
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $status;

    /**
     * @param string $status Valid values are 'new', 'accepted', and 'rejected'
     *
     * @throws InvalidBookingStatusException
     */
    public function setStatus($status){
        if (! in_array($status, $this->statusMap)){
            throw new InvalidBookingStatusException();
        }
        $this->status = $this->statusMapReverse[$status];
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStatus(){
        return $this->statusMap[$this->status];
    }

    /**
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getStatusCode(){
        return $this->status;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getStatusMap(){
       return $this->statusMap;
    }

}
```

I find I use this pattern pretty frequently when I need to model this kind of enumeration-like data.  It has a few nice features:

1) Status is stored as in integer in the db.

2) Calling code doesn't ever need to care about those (integer) values, unless it wants to.

3) Calling code is protected against typos/invalid status since setStatus validates strings (can only be checked at runtime, but hey)

4) Booking::getStatusMap() makes it easy to generate select boxes, etc.

You could expand setStatus to accept either a string or integer (status-code), and still validate, if you wanted to be able to set status by code.

The disadvantages (compared to using constants), are mainly:

1) Querying by status becomes a bit of a hassle.  Client code needs to getStatusMap() and find codes.

2) IDEs won't be quite as helpful in telling calling code what valid statuses are (though the phpdoc annotation on setStatus() can help, if you keep it up-to-date.

3) Invalid status throws an exception at runtime, while with constants you find out at compile-time.

--

Final note, I don't see the need for a BookingManager at all.  Yes, entities are just plain objects, but that doesn't mean they can't contain logic to manage their own state.

Answer (score 1):

I like handling those kind of issues in a generic way (a bit of an overkill if all you need is a status, but what project ever needed only one enum-like field?);

First, I create a "GenericOptionEntity", having the following fields:

- ID
- Tag
- Label
- Entity
- Field

And a one to many relationship to associate the entity (or the base entity, in case of a generic "status") to the appropriate field.

The "entity" and "field" fields help identify the proper options for form types.

The GenericOptionRepository should implement a "getOptionByTag", so that you wouldn't have to use IDs to get the proper entity. Also, a generic method for getting appropriate options for the calling method \ field.

Lastly (depending on the case), a bunch of interfaces sometimes come in handy, especially for making entities "Statusable" when you need it.

I really like this approach, mostly because:

- It makes sense :)
- Adding and removing options can be done by an admin, via GUI
- Easy to filter the appropriate options for the view / controller tiers
- Allows re-use of all the helper methods required
- Does not clutter your project with mini-classes created for 4 DB rows

Answer (score 1):

I would go with Tom's approach and make the status table look like this :

- id
- description
- isAccepted (bool)
- isRejected (bool)

And the values like this :

- id : 1
- description : New
- isAccepted : 0
- isRejected : 0
- id : 2
- description : Accepted
- isAccepted : 1
- isRejected : 0
- id : 3
- description : Rejected
- isAccepted : 0
- isRejected : 1

You then query with isAccepted or isRejected without having to worry about the id.

Answer (score 0):

I recently worked out something similar in a MenuItem entity and three constant 'types'.

The approach I like includes adding some additional 'is' methods. I placed them right in the entity, but that approach is up to you. I'm not sure there is a single 'right way'.

```
<?php

class Booking
{
    const STATUS_NEW = 0;
    const STATUS_ACCEPTED = 1;
    const STATUS_REJECTED = 2;

    protected $status;

    public function setBookingStatus($status)
    {
        $this->status = $status;
    }

    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    public function isStatusNew()
    {
        return $this->status === self::STATUS_NEW;
    }

    public function isStatusAccepted()
    {
        return $this->status === self::STATUS_ACCEPTED;
    }

    public function isStatusRejected()
    {
        return $this->status === self::STATUS_REJECTED;
    }
}
```

That allows you to use some easier logic in your Twig templates (YMMV):

```
{% if booking.statusAccepted %}

{% elseif booking.statusRejected %}

{% else %}
```

In this way you can keep a similar Twig syntax to your constants.

Comment: The problem starts when I have 20 templates where I have to display the status name, I have to copy-paste the whole if-else structure over and over again

Comment: That is correct. What I suggested is the [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) approach, so as soon as you want to associate meta-data (name, date) or reverse lookup (which bookings are accepted?), you should use an association as @Tomdarkness describes

Comment: What's bad with copy paste code ? Anyway in twig You can use shared templates and You'll have that code only once